# Why ubuntu-mate-desktop depends firefox?

Tags: package-management, firefox, mate

I want to do `apt-get purge firefox` in ubuntu14.04LTS, but it show that my `ubuntu-mate-desktop` will also be removed if I do it.

````
$ sudo apt-get purge firefox
[sudo] password for tiger: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  caja-extensions-common caja-gksu caja-open-terminal caja-sendto dconf-editor
  eom eom-common libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common
  libmate-sensors-applet-plugin0 libmatedict6 mate-applets mate-applets-common
  mate-icon-theme-faenza mate-media mate-netspeed mate-sensors-applet
  mate-themes mate-utils mate-utils-common pluma pluma-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox* ubuntu-mate-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 173 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
```
````

I view this link:[ubuntu-mate-desktop package depends](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/x11/mate-desktop), it seems that no `firefox` in it.
Why this case happen?

Comment: What were you doing *before* you decided to purge Firefox? `apt-get autoremove` seems to want to remove a lot of useful packages!

Comment: @DKBose I don't know I do something strangely may result in this case. The package mentioned by `apt-get autoremove` seems all related with `mate-desktop`. And I think the answer of thomasrutter should be right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mate-desktop` and `ubuntu-mate-desktop` are two separate things with different goals.

When you checked the dependencies of `mate-desktop` you did not see Firefox, because `mate-desktop` is only for the installation of Mate itself, and does not bring with it a suite of programs.

`ubuntu-mate-desktop` is the "full" mate desktop which brings with it a suite of programs, including Firefox.  You can see its dependencies here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-mate-desktop

If you remove Firefox it will necessarily remove `ubuntu-mate-desktop`, but that doesn't remove Mate itself, only the super package that includes Mate and all those other software programs.  Assuming the other parts of it were installed during Ubuntu installation, or have been marked as manually installed since, they will remain.